# Compare text stored in each row across 2 columns in R

Tags: r, text-mining, cosine-similarity, lsa

I have 2 vectors

```
a=c("abc","def","ghi","jkl")  
b=c("abc","dez","gyx","mno")
```

How can I get cosine values to compare corresponding entries? In this case, I need to be able to say the 1st entries in each vector is perfectly similar and 2nd entry in each vector is slightly similar... and the last entry in each vector is completely dissimilar?   I tried the lsa package - but I can get an overall cosine value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringdist` package

```
stringdist(a, b, method = "cosine")
#[1] 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000
```